# Angular storage check fails

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have data stored in my localStorage and in my component `OnInit` I check if that data exist filter the table results if not, show all results.

The issue is that this functionality sometimes works and sometimes not! I'm not sure what cause the issue but it's most highly to fail when I hard refresh my page `Ctrl+F5`

## Code `commented`

```
searchbar_values: boolean = false;
tableSearch_column: boolean = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Get all data from server
    this.getList(null);

    // Condition 1 (first storage values)
    const getstoredata = store.get('searchbar_values')
    if (getstoredata) {
      this.searchbar_values = true;
      this.tableSearch_column = false;
    }

    // Condition 2 (second storage values)
    const getstoredata2 = store.get('tableSearch_column')
    if (getstoredata2) {
      this.tableSearch_column = true;
      this.searchbar_values = false;
    }

    // if first condition happened do this (sometimes fail)
    if (this.searchbar_values) {
      const storeData = store.get('searchbar_values')
      this.globalSearchService.searchTerm.next(storeData.value);
      this.globalSearchService.searchTerm.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
        this.searchTerm = newValue;
        if (newValue != null) {
          this.visible = false;
          this.globalSearchService.getSearchBar(newValue).subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.listOfData = data.data;
            this.limit = data.limit
            this.totalPages = data.total
            this.page = data.page
            this.pages = data.pages
            this.isSpinning = false;
            store.set('searchbar_values', { value: newValue })
            this.searchbar_values = true;

            if (this.tableSearch_column) {
              store.remove('tableSearch_column');
              this.tableSearch_column = false;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }

    // if second condition happened do this (sometimes fail)
    if (this.tableSearch_column) {
      const storeData = store.get('tableSearch_column')
      this.isSpinning = true;
      this.globalSearchService.getTableFilter(storeData.field, storeData.op, 'none', storeData.value).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.listOfData = [];
        this.listOfData = data.data;
        this.limit = data.limit
        this.totalPages = data.total
        this.page = data.page
        this.pages = data.pages
        this.isSpinning = false;
      });
    }
}
```

**PS:** `tableSearch_column` and `searchbar_values` will never be stored at the same time in localStorage because I always remove one before storing other one.

> So the logic is either one of them is exist or none of them.

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1):

## Solved

I've moved my storage check into `constructor` like this:

```
constructor(
    //....
  ) {
    //...

    const getstoredata = store.get('searchbar_values')
    if (getstoredata) {
      this.searchbar_values = true;
      this.tableSearch_column = false;
    }
    const getstoredata2 = store.get('tableSearch_column')
    if (getstoredata2) {
      this.tableSearch_column = true;
      this.searchbar_values = false;
    }
}
```

And then called my conditions in `ngOnInit` as you see in my question above. now everytime it calls localStorage and return correct values.